Error in build.gradle.kts in flutter when running apps
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'G:\kasirku\android\build.gradle' line: 7

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'kotlin_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Exited (1).

How to fix it ?
Use the flutter and firebase for database

Please edit to include the file. Looks line it's probably just a typo in the code.
